# Reverting previous day's mysql with shadow copy

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, vss

I've followed a few walk-throughs on how to restore a shadow copy of mysql on windows 2008 r2 and the information doesn't seem to jive.

They indicate that the mysql database file is located in the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data directory but I'm only finding three folders mysql, performace_schema, and test. None containing anything that even looks like database data.

We're going to move to another back-up schema but that's for another day.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database data was located in a hidden directory. C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5